# PHP Converting simple numbers in a gif to text?

Tags: php, ocr, gif

I am trying to automate a process which at the moment is done by hand.

I have several gif images which contain a currency symbol + a numeric value just like this one:

[image: example image of number]

I am trying to obtain the numeric value directly from the GIF image but it looks like my strategy isn't working properly (I have tried several solutions concerning OCR).

Do you have any suggestions on how I could do this?

I have been thinking at saving somewhere an array of possible images which could be single numbers like 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 and search within the image for each occurrence of these numbers starting from left to right in order to create a numeric string with the solutions but I really don't know where to start.

Some more information: images contain always this kind of information:

- dollar sign
- numeric value
- decimal point
- numeric cents
- images always have the same font

As you can see according to the position of the number in the numeric value, the number itself will have a different background since the color is not plain.

Comment: This is very similar to the CAPTCHA cracking problem - search for that phrase and you may find something that is useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crop it with `imagemagick` and scan with `tesseract`

Comment: hello! thanks for the suggestion. i have been trying this solution and it worked only once. I have read that tesseract can be trained in case it makes mistakes, could you explain me how please?

Comment: what did you try? that's an answer, not the solution to *your* problem